# Alternatives to the PS223 power supply monitoring IC

Tags: power-supply, alternatives

I am repairing a power supply that (among other faults) has a dead PS223 chip. This chip monitors the output voltages for over/under voltage and over current. It also outputs a "power good" signal to the motherboard.

The problem is that I cannot get that chip locally. I can order it on eBay, but it would take a long time to arrive.

However, I doubt that this chip is unique in its function - maybe there are other chips (that I can hopefully get faster) that do the same function with minimal modifications to the circuit?

Comment: Check http://www.techpowerup.com/articles//overclocking/psu/160/9 and each one listed has a link to the datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be a specialized IC that replaces lots of analog circuitry. Some simpler ATX power supplies use discrete circuits to generate the power good signal after a delay.

[image]

This example uses an LM393 comparator, for instance, to check the +5V rail and to make sure that OVP is not fired before allowing the power good signal to assert. In a pinch, you could try and replicate something simple like this.